# Volvo V60 Daytime Running Light - what is the bulb type? Instructions to replace bulb? Or what relay/fuse to replace?

Tags: volvo, lights

[image: Volvo V60 daytime running light]

That ^ is a 2010 Volvo V60, UK, with one daytime running light that doesn't work. (The one on the other side is fine).

So I want to replace the bulb rather than drive to the Volvo dealer (which isn't conveniently located) and have them do it. Also I'm thinking it'll be cheaper to do it myself, and replacing bulbs is easy, right?

I've looked in the manual and it doesn't say anything at all about this light. So I don't know what bulb type to get or how to replace it.

I've also looked online (Google etc) and I'm just not finding anything. Also I've not found anything on Volvo's website or in their online version of the manual.

So my question is:

- if this is a blown bulb then what bulb type do I need? Or do I need a whole new sealed unit?
- alternatively, might the problem be a fuse or a relay and if so which one? (again I can't find this in the manual).
- what are instructions for accessing the bulb to replace it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Volvo V60 does not have bulbs, but is illuminated by LED strips. They are moulded into the assembly. Because of the recent manufacture of your vehicle the after market will not yet have a pattern part for it. You will need to visit a Volvo dealer for a replacement.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Allan. If they're LEDs presumably they're quite unlikely to fail after such a short period of time? So maybe I should be looking more closely into the possibility that it's just a fuse that's gone? That would only make sense if both sides of the car don't share a fuse, because the equivalent light on the other side is fine.

Comment: Although they do vary across engine and specification, DRL are shown as running on fuse N0.28. They show both units running off of the same fuse, so the lamp assembly or wiring appear to be at fault.

Answer (score 3):

Before you go off to the Stealership to have the bulb replaced, you may want to see if the bulb has lost connectivity at the plug. Since these are LED bulbs, they don't go bad very often or very fast. I believe you should be able to access the plug by removing the main headlight in your car. While [this video](http://www.carcarekiosk.com/video/2012_Volvo_S60_T5_2.5L_5_Cyl._Turbo/lights/daylight_running) shows you how to remove the main headlight, it's a little cheesy. You shouldn't have to remove the wire connectors to the headlight to get to the DRL. As far as the DRL, try unplugging/plugging it a few times to see if this rejuvenates the connection.

Also, I doubt the problem is a fuse, since normally when you have two bulbs like this (as you do), both bulbs run off the same fuse/relay. Since one is working, you can rule this out.