# Volvo V60/S60 <2012 LED bulb replacement

Tags: volvo, led

The LED bulb unit that sits between the headlamp assembly and the rad has gone. I have bought a new complete unit (two led strips inside) but cannot see how to unplug the old one and plug in the new one. It looks like I have to take the bumper off to access the connection which is a big job. Is that right or am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: I think there is a cover on the rear you have to remove first....https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ROADHgJQWI

Comment: Related: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/volvo-v60-daytime-running-light-what-is-the-bulb-type-instructions-to-replace